# Can this garbage disposal be saved ? Black gunk doesnt drip down to cabinet floor but my skin crawled when i saw this?

Tags: mold, garbage-disposal, leaking

Garbage disposal is about 3 years old. It got jammed , so i tried to find the reset button on bottom.  It wouldnt budge so i got a flashlight and got on the floor to make sure i was pressing right thing.  I was horrified when i saw this nasty sight in the middle of the garbage disposal. Looks like dried slime. It doesnt run down the machine or to the cabinet floor but something definitly is wrong.  I got disposal un jammed and it works fine but underneath scares me. Is it worth tryin to fix ?[image]

Comment: One way to find out would be to take it apart and clean it.  Looks like possibly a combination of corrosion and leak or possibly corrosion caused by leak.  There look to be signs that at some point there were drippings there.

Comment: If it is jammed it should have come with a key. Some are hex wrenches some are square stock bent into a L shape.  Un plug and try turning in both directions if there is an arrow for normal operation try going the opposite direction. The thing that is jammed may release very easily in the opposite direction where continuing to force it in the normal direction may bend things. As far as the gunk I have seen much worse

Comment: It is interesting to me that gunk looks to have run down the metal but not onto the gray of the disposal which is clean.  I wonder if that rust / gunk predates the current disposal.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like whoever installed the disposal didn't tighten up the locking bracket enough. You have three brackets in there. Two are for the mounting to the sink and they are not leaking.  See picture below of standard installations.

[image]

The lowest bracket is what holds the disposal to the sink fitting. You can undo that bracket by turning it counterclockwise with a screwdriver or allan wrench like in the picture. You'll want to disconnect the pipes and turn off the power first. Once you unlock that bracket the disposal will drop down. Clean it off, make sure the rubber flange is securely in place and put the disposal back in place and turn the locking bracket clockwise while holding the disposal in place.The bracket has to attach to the upper bracket in three spots, make sure they are all engaged. Make sure you tighten the bracket all the way.

This requires some strength and working in a slightly confined area so if you don't feel comfortable doing it, get some help ahead of time